# Regex change uppercase to lowercase in anchor tag

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I want any regex expression where can change all Uppercase to lowercase 
E.g Input 
`<a href="/Category">Text</a> 
<a href="/Abc-XYZ">Text</a>
<a href='/CategorY/'>Text</a>`

Output is
`<a href="/category">Text</a> 
<a href="/abc-xyz">Text</a>
<a href='/category/'>Text</a>`

I am trying to `<a(\w*)<\/a>` into `\L$1` but not geting exect result

Answer (score 0):

Find all the characters until the first **>** (lazy quantifier): `<a(.*?)>`

Replace all the matched group to lowercase: `<a\L$1>`

Here's a [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/80frDu/1) (also tested in *notepad++*)

Answer (score 0):

search: `(<a href=['"])([^'"]+)(.*)`

replace: `$1\L$2\E$3`

The key is to use `\E` to stop the case substitution. I am not familiar with the tool notepad++. Don't know how would it do the replacement. So I just gave the pattern to match the whole line. It could be shortened.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=href=['"])[^'"]+`
- Replace with: `\L$0`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=            # start lookbehind, zero-length assertion, makes sure we have before:
    href=['"]   # href= followed by single or double quote
)               # end lookbehind
[^'"]+          # 1 or more any character that is not single or double quote
```

**Replacement:**

```
\L      # lowercase the following
$0      # content of group 0 (i.e. the whole match)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
href="/category">Text</a> 
<a href="/abc-xyz">Text</a>
<a href='/category/'>Text</a>
```